# Mozmill : list of keywords --> first result URLs in Google

Tags: web-crawler, ui-automation, mozmill

I have a list of keywords. With Mozmill, I'd like to get the first result URL for each of those keyword when doing a search on Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to provide MozMill with a list of URLs which it should crawl, so you have to generate the URLs of the pages you'd like to crawl. Google supports various queries, here is the format of the URL: `http://www.google.com/search?q=keyword`

You have to replace "keyword" with your actual keyword, so let's say your keywords include the words `dentist`, `iphone`, `eye drops`, you would generate the following 3 URLs:

`http://www.google.com/search?q=dentist`
`http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone`
`http://www.google.com/search?q=eye%20drops` (note: the space is URL encoded)

Here are a couple of more detailed explanations all the parameters you can have in Google URL:

- [Google search URLs revealed or How to create your own search URL](http://www.our-picks.com/archives/2007/01/30/google-search-urls-revealed-or-how-to-create-your-own-search-url/)
- [Google Search URL Parameters – Query String Anatomy](http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy/)

From then on you're going to have to do some work in order to properly select the result URLs (i.e. you have to write some code). I don't think MozMill offers that functionality out of the box and I don't think there are any other crawlers that do.